# Sonar warning about statement always evaluating to false after immediate restTemplate postForObject call

Tags: java, sonarqube, resttemplate, lint

example code:

```
      Info info = restTemplate.postForObject(connectionString, requestEntity, 
         Info.class);

      if (info == null) {
         throw new ApplicationException(Constants.NO_RESULT_ERROR_CODE);
      }
```

Question: why does sonar give me warning ("Change this issue so that it does not always evaluate to "false.").  I've been able to prove that `if (info == null)` evaluates to true when the requestEntity doesn't contain a payload that's found in the db.  So how can I get rid of this false positive?

Comment: Indeed [`RestTemplate.postForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) has a `@Nullable` result. Is there no other `info.<something>`, that is did you erase some code here? Maybe sonarqube ignored the `@Nullable` or did you have an older spring library?

Comment: There is no @Nullable anywhere in this class, where would it go?  No there is no info.something

Comment: doesn't nullable mean you can put a null param into the postForObject method, not that the method can return null?

Comment: my bad `@nullable` means `A common Spring annotation to declare that annotated elements can be null under some circumstance.`

Comment: @Zeratul and @Deadpool thanks, I erred evidently, as both one parameter and the method itself was annotated by an `@Nullable`. Maybe a historical thing, as parameter annotation is newer.